# How to round numbers and replace small values in table by "<0.1" in R

Tags: r, dplyr, rounding, mutate

I have a large data table containing values ("c" and "d" in "exampledata") which i would like to alter in the following way:

- if group >1000 and value >1: round to 0 digits
- if group >1000 and value <1: paste "<1"
- if group <1000 and value >0.1: round to 1 digit
- if group <1000 and value <0.1: paste "<0.1"

```
exampledata <- data.table(
  a = c("aa", "bb", "cc", "aa", "bb", "cc"),
  b = c("a", "b", "c", "a", "a", "b"),
  c = c(0, 0.05, 0.5, 50, 10, 6.898),
  d = c(10000, 153.789, 123.22, 55.11, 0.0000025, 0.06),
  group = c(11000, 50220, 10, 23, 62, 5)
)
```

This would be the desired solution i am looking for:

```
desired_solution <- data.table(
  a = c("aa", "bb", "cc", "aa", "bb", "cc"),
  b = c("a", "b", "c", "a", "a", "b"),
  c = c(0, "<1", 0.5, 50.0, 10.0, 6.9),
  d = c(10000, 154, 123.2, 55.1, "<0.1", "<0.1"),
  group = c(11000, 50220, 10, 23, 62, 5)
)
```

```
> desired_solution
    a b   c     d group
1: aa a   0 10000 11000
2: bb b  <1   154 50220
3: cc c 0.5 123.2    10
4: aa a  50  55.1    23
5: bb a  10  <0.1    62
6: cc b 6.9  <0.1     5
```

I have tried:

```
desired_solution <- exampledata %>%
  mutate_at(vars(c(3:4)), case_when(.>0.1 & group < 1000 ~ round(., digits = 1),
                                    .<0.1 & group < 1000 ~ "<0.1",
                                    .>1 & group > 1000 ~ round(., digits = 0),
                                    .<1 & group > 1000 ~ "<1"))
```

This of course did not work. I dont know how to solve this problem. If i replace the smaller numbers (e.g. <0.1) by a character ("<0.1) i can no longer round the remaining values and if i round the values first I will no longer have the smaller numbers to display!
I will be gratefull for any ideas.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that with `case_when` all RHS values (see `?case_when`)

> must evaluate to the same type of vector.

Hence, to fix you issue you have to convert the numerics to characters using `as.charatcer`

```r
library(dplyr)

exampledata %>%
  mutate(across(3:4, ~ case_when(
    . > 0.1 & group < 1000 ~ as.character(round(., digits = 1)),
    . < 0.1 & group < 1000 ~ "<0.1",
    . > 1 & group > 1000 ~ as.character(round(., digits = 0)),
    . < 1 & group > 1000 ~ "<1"
  )))
#>    a b   c     d group
#> 1 aa a  <1 10000 11000
#> 2 bb b  <1   154 50220
#> 3 cc c 0.5 123.2    10
#> 4 aa a  50  55.1    23
#> 5 bb a  10  <0.1    62
#> 6 cc b 6.9  <0.1     5
```